# Javascript: Focus is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm writing a registration form and am trying to sort out some validation. I got this same problem when my validate button was inside the `<form>` however to fix this I just moved it out as I guessed the button was causing the form to refresh.
However now after inserting multiple if statement into the "ValidateForm()" function this error message has seemed to come back.

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Forename.focus is not a function
>       at ValidateForm (Login Form Complex.html?Forename=&Surname=&Username=&Password=&Email=:79)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Login Form Complex.html?Forename=&Surname=&Username=&Password=&Email=:63)**

```js
function ValidateForm() {
  var Forename = document.getElementById("Forename").value;
  var Surname = document.getElementById("Surname").value;
  var Username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
  var Password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
  var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
  var Errors = 0

  if (Forename == "") {
    document.LoginForm.Forename.focus();
    Forename.focus();
    Errors = Errors + 1
  }

  if (Surname == "") {
    document.LoginForm.Forename.focus();
    Surname.focus();
    Errors = Errors + 1

  }

  if (Username == "") {
    document.LoginForm.Forename.focus();
    Username.focus();
    Errors = Errors + 1

  }

  if (Password == "") {
    document.LoginForm.Forename.focus();
    Password.focus();
    Errors = Errors + 1

  }
  if (Errors != 0) {
    alert("Please fill in the highlighted boxes")
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(LoginBack.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: century gothic;
}

.loginbox {
  width: 420px;
  height: 680px;
  background: #5CDB95;
  color: #05386B;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 70px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -75px;
  left: calc(50% - 75px);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #05386B;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #379683;
}

.loginbox button[type="Submit"] {
  border: 2px solid #05386B;
  background: #379683;
  height: 40px;
  width: 362px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: ;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.loginbox button[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #8EE4AF;
}

.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #379683;
}

.loginbox a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #8EE4AF;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8B0000;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #8B0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <img src="Logo.jpg" class="avatar">
  <h1> Create Account </h1>
  <form name="LoginForm">
    <p>Forename<p><input type="text" name="Forename" id="Forename" placeholder="Enter Forename here">
    <p>Surname<p><input type="text" name="Surname" id="Surname" placeholder="Enter Surname here">
    <p>Username<p><input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" placeholder="Enter Username here">
    <p>Password<p><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="Enter Password here">
    <p>Email<p><input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter Email here">
    <!-- 
    <p>Gender<p><input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender" value="Male">Male</input>
                <input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender" value="Female">Female</input>
    -->
    <button onclick="ButtonSubmit()" type="Submit" value="True" name="ButtonSubmit"> Submit </button><br /><br />
    <a href="#"> Forgot your password? </a><br />
    <a href="#"> Already got an account? </a><br /><br />
  </form>
  <button onclick="ValidateForm()"> Validate </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You might also need to close your input tags. <input type="...." />

Comment: `var Forename = document.getElementById("Forename"); .... if (Forename.value=="") ...`

Comment: because you have a string.... you can not focus a string

Comment: Also PLEASE give form an ID and do `document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit=ValidateForm;` instead of onclick of the button - you will not stop the submission unless you do "return ValidateForm()" on the onclick so the submit even is much better

Comment: Or better yet, `document.getElementById("idHere").addEventListener("submit", ValidateForm);`

Comment: @Stradosphere self-closing "/" characters do nothing at all in HTML5. It's not necessary to close `<input>` tags or any other tags with empty content type (like `<br>`)

Comment: @Stradosphere `input` elements don't get closed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus To be pragmatic, there will not be other events on the submit so I prefer onsubmit to be as backwards compatible as possible

Comment: @mplungjan Are you saying that you don't believe that a `submit` event might need to have multiple callbacks registered for it?

Comment: @ScottMarcus - they can be `<input ... />` but it is the lack of `</p>` that is confusing the prettyprint

Comment: @mplungjan The closing tag for `p` elements is optional. I don't take advantage of that fact, but it is valid.

Comment: @ScottMarcus In this case for this user there will NEVER EVER IN A THOUSAND YEARS need to be another submit handler added - I have never seen more than one since 1996 by the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Forename` variable is not holding a reference to a DOM element. It is referencing the `.value` of that element. The same is true for all of your other DOM variables.

```
var Forename = document.getElementById("Forename").value;
```

The `value` doesn't have a `.focus()` method. The element does.

In general, it's best not to set variables to properties of DOM elements because, if you determine later that you need a different DOM property, you have to scan the DOM again for a reference you already scanned for. Additionally, setting variables to the DOM elements themselves, and not properties of the elements, will prevent your error, which is very common.

So, change your variables to be set up like this:

```
var Forename = document.getElementById("Forename");
```

And then, when you need the value, you can just write:

```
Forename.value
```

And, when you want to use the `focus()` method, just write:

```
Forename.focus();
```

You can access whatever aspect of the element you want if you always start from the element itself.

Comment: Close as typo type?

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think it's a typo. I think it's more of a common coding paradigm that ultimately renders itself as an anti-pattern.

Comment: I like to close such questions when they have all the info needed in the comment to the question. It is really poor quality coding

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment, what would you suggest I do instead? I'm still learning a lot of the basics of HTML/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

E.g.`Forename` var have the value of `Forename` input element then:

```
var Forename = document.getElementById("Forename"); //DOM element

var fornameValue = Forename.value //value

Forename.focus()  //focus function
```